# Get file from repository using Atlassian Bitbucket API

Tags: java, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have a Java Application that implements a hook using the Atlassian Bitbucket API.

The class that implements the hook is defined as follows:

```
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export.ExportAsService;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.PreRepositoryHook;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.RepositoryHookRequest;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.PreRepositoryHookContext;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.RepositoryHookResult;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.hook.repository.PreRepositoryHookRequest;
import com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.Repository;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

/* Other imports */

@ExportAsService({SCMAdapter.class})
public class SCMAdapter implements PreRepositoryHook<RepositoryHookRequest>, ISCMAdapter{
     /*Methods from both interfaces*/
}
```

The methods from the `ISCMAdapter` interface are irrelevant for this problem.

The `PreRepositoryHook` interface contains two methods. One of them is the following:

```
public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext context, @Nonnull RepositoryHookRequest request){
    /*Returns a RepositoryHookResult object */
}
```

I can obtain the repository involved in the hook with the following call:

```
Repository repo = request.getRepository();
```

From that object, I can obtain the project's key, the slug, the ID, the name and the state:

```
String pkey=repo.getProject().getKey();
String slug=repo.getSlug();
String name=repo.getName();
int id=repo.getId();
Repository.State state=repo.getState();
```

The method is currently working fine. However, I got a requirement that each repository must have a hidden directory with the same name for all repositories (lets say ".myHiddenDir") and that directory must contain a YAML file named config.yml

Is it possible, with the information obtained as listed above to obtain the content of an specific file in the repo?

Thanks in advance.

P.D.: If you find that this description is lacking more info, please let me know and I will check the code.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/christiangalsterer/stash-filehooks-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/christiangalsterer/stash/filehooks/plugin/hook/FileNameHook.java#L65